# Is there an incremental Android ADT build?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, adt

I use very large resource files in my project (movies).
Whenever I change just one line in my code and debug on my device it seems to copy all files again.

Is there a kind of incremental build  in ADT? SO it copies only the changed parts?

Comment: only one part is copied into emulator/device: yourApp.apk file

Comment: could you explain in more detail what this has to do with my question? thanks

Comment: "SO it copies only the changed parts?" i said that there is only **ONE** file that is copied during new app install: complete apk file

Comment: Yes, but even if it is in one big file it could copy only the changed parts, right? I mean many filesystems can do that.